# Mongo Java Driver 4+ Issue with Constructor

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver, mongo-java

I have an issue while migrating mongo version 3 to version 4.

With version 3 we have below constructor which accept 4 arguments

```
ObjectId(Date date, int machineIdentifier, short processIdentifier, int counter)
```

> V3 API:  https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html

With version 4, the above constructor has private access.
So what will be an alternative to create ObjectId with **machineIdentifier** and **processIdentifier**?

> V4 API:
> https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/apidocs/bson/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html

And still document shows "Creates an ObjectId using the given time, machine identifier, process identifier, and counter." (Refer attached image) but constructor accepting 2 parameters only, seems like a mistake in the document?

[image]

Comment: The [3.12 documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,short,int)) marks it deprecated and suggests to use `ObjectId(int timestamp, int counter)` instead. The documentation of that method mentioning machine and process identifier is likely a copy/paste error.

Comment: Agree, But the question is "what will be an alternative to create ObjectId with machineIdentifier and processIdentifier ?"

Comment: That is why it was a comment, but I guess the answer is: there isn't.